Can SwiftUI MapKit Polylines be selected?
The title is the question. I have wrapped Polylines in a Hashable, Identifiable struct, and I'm tagging them with their ids, and I think I've passed in the correct selection: binding to the map, but it doesn't work. I can't find any documentation that says Polylines can't be selected.
Here's a minimal sketch:
    import SwiftUI
    import CoreLocation
    import MapKit
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var selection: UUID? = nil
    
        struct HashablePolyline: Identifiable, Hashable {
            static func == (lhs: ContentView.HashablePolyline, rhs: ContentView.HashablePolyline) -> Bool {
                lhs.id == rhs.id
            }
            func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
                hasher.combine(id)
            }
    
            var id = UUID()
            var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
            var pl: MapPolyline {
                MapPolyline(coordinates: coordinates)
            }
        }

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                if let selection {
                    Text("Selected: \(selection)")
                } else {
                    Text("Selected: nil")
                }
                Map(selection: $selection) {
                    ForEach(polylines) { p in
                        p.pl.tag(p.id)
                            .stroke(p.id == selection ? .red : .blue, lineWidth: 5)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }

        private var polylines: [HashablePolyline] {
            coords.map { HashablePolyline(coordinates: $0) }
        }

        private let coords: [[CLLocationCoordinate2D]] = [
            [
                .init(latitude: 55, longitude: -3),
                .init(latitude: 54.9, longitude: -3.1),
            ],
            [
                .init(latitude: 55.5, longitude: -3.2),
                .init(latitude: 54.8, longitude: -3.3),
            ]
        ]
    
    }


MKMapView can't even detect touches on polylines. It is highly unlikely that this is supported. Use a MapReader and TapGesture to detect it manually.

@Sweeper, I thought that was perhaps the case, but was hopeful as the only instance method that MapPolyline has is mapItemDetailSelectionAccessory see here.

That's a method for MapContent, not specifically for MapPolyline.
